# Failed to fetch cdrom:* warnings in apt, how to fix them?

Tags: apt

I’m a newbie with this Ubuntu system, I often use windows.. anyway my uncle gave me a laptop which uses Ubuntu 10 or something and I updated it to 12.04.

the system popped out this Ubuntu one and I clicked the install button yet several minutes some error came out as seen below.

```
W:Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 10.04.1 LTS_Lucid Lynx_-Release i386 (20100816.1)/dists/lucid/main/binary-i386/Packages 
Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
,W:Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 10.04.1 LTS_Lucid Lynx_-Release i386 (20100816)/dists/lucid/restricted/binary-i386/Packages 
Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
,E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

Try running `gksu software-properties-gtk` and uncheck the 10.04 CDROMs.

Answer (score 0):

Or if you want a solution in the terminal use:

```
sudo sed -i 's/deb\ cdrom/#deb\ cdrom/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo sed -i 's/deb-src\ cdrom/#deb\ cdrom/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

The `-i` will edit the files in place, meaning that it will edit the file itself.